# java class file automatically converted into singleton file. why? how to restore?

Tags: android

While Creating app my java class file automatically converted like this after the latest update. why?

how to restore it again to my original file?

[image]

Comment: this is not anything called singleton file. But your project is probably corrupt

Comment: How to restore it.. anyone?